# Clickonce Deployment - installation error (Winforms .Net 3.5 C# Windows 7)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, clickonce

I have recently changed my build machine from Windows XP to Windows 7. I am still using Visual Studio 2008 (Winforms C# .Net 3.5 Windows 7). I also have created a new Temporary Security Certificate on the new machine. The Clickonce Installation was working fine from the same UNC share from the old XP machine but it is not working on the new machine. The error I get on the client machine is 'Application cannot started, contact Application vendor'. I have pasted the error details from the log below:
**ERROR DETAILS**
    Following errors were detected during this operation.

```
* [4/29/2014 4:37:07 PM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by removing circular references of the MS Office Excel dlls.
Thanks to the author of the link below:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e6c0a0ca-fbf0-47e2-8681-bc03471d09f6/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range?forum=winformssetup